# Error while parsing data from jena to j2ee

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jena

I am trying to parse the resultset stored in a file using jena to a webpage using j2ee. I am getting an error while trying to parse the resultset. I am able to pass on normal string from the java class to index.jsp

```
    package example;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.apache.jena.query.Query;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import org.apache.jena.riot.Lang;
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr;


import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class webApp extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sparqlQueryString1 = "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"+
            "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>"+
            "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+
            "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
            "PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>"+
            "PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>"+
            "PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>"+
            "PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>"+
            "PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>"+
            "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>"+
            "select ?p ?o where {"+
            "  dbr:Cristiano_Ronaldo ?p ?o "+

            "}";
                    Query query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQueryString1);
                    QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);

                    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
                    FileOutputStream oFile;
                    oFile = new FileOutputStream("score.txt", false);

                    ResultSetFormatter.out(oFile, results, query);
                    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ;

                    qexec.close() ;


    resp.getWriter().println(oFile);
}

}
```

Error Log:

```
Jun 29, 2016 4:21:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Dynamic4] has started
Jun 29, 2016 4:21:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
SEVERE: Exception starting Context with name [/Dynamic4]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Dynamic4]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3954)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jena/sparql/core/Prologue
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jena.sparql.core.Prologue
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 22 more

Jun 29, 2016 4:21:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Dynamic4] is completed
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @limonik - error log added. This is when I reload. It gives the error only once. After that the server wont simply start until eclipse is restarted.

Comment: Are you sure you have added `jena-arq` on your pom.xml? If yes, Try using latest version of it.

Comment: @Runcorn - I am not using maven. I just added the userlibrary of jena to the project.

Comment: Ummm... Then try checking the generated war $WAR/WEB-INF/lib to check if the library has been included or not...

Comment: @Runcorn - I have added the jena jar files to the location. It server starts without error.. But still the query result is not being displayed on the webpage... It is just blank result.. I have tried the same code on an empty java project and it works fine. But in here it doesnt display the result in the webpage.

Comment: @Runcorn - I have fixed all the issues. However how can I display the result in a table format with predicates and objects of the query into the jsp.. Write now its just displaying in a println alltogether.